# create text reading data from a file

Tags: scripting, csv

I have a csv file which has a list of 600 numbers in the following format

442030580306

442030580307

I need it to output the file in one long file like the below from reading the numbers above

```
         "new-request-uri-user-part:442030580306": {
            "query_string": {
              "query": "new-request-uri-user-part:442030580306",
              "analyze_wildcard": true
            }
          },
          "new-request-uri-user-part:442030580307": {
            "query_string": {
              "query": "new-request-uri-user-part:442030580307",
              "analyze_wildcard": true
            }
          },
```

Any ideas how best to achieve this?

Comment: yes repeated with each new number it reads from a separate file

Comment: or maybe, it would be enough to get the result as a one main object

Comment: Do any of the existing answers solve your problem? If so, please indicate so with the checkmark, or else let us know what's missing. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we want eventually obtain a JSON data - [***jq***](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) is the right tool:

`numbers.csv` file contents:

```
442030580306
442030580307
```

***jq*** solution:

```
jq -s '"new-request-uri-user-part:" as $pfx | reduce [.[]|tostring][] as 
        $n ({}; .[($pfx + $n)] |= {"query_string": {"query": ($pfx + $n), "analyze_wildcard": true }})' numbers.csv
```

The output:

```
{
  "new-request-uri-user-part:442030580306": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "new-request-uri-user-part:442030580306",
      "analyze_wildcard": true
    }
  },
  "new-request-uri-user-part:442030580307": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "new-request-uri-user-part:442030580307",
      "analyze_wildcard": true
    }
  }
}
```

---

- `"new-request-uri-user-part:" as $pfx` - assigning the common phrase `"new-request-uri-user-part:"` to varible `$pfx`
- `reduce [.[]|tostring][] as $n ({}; ...)` - performing the reduction operation upon the list of input numbers

Answer (score 2):

Simply, with printf:

```
while read number
do
  printf '        "new-request-uri-user-part:%s": {
            "query_string": {
              "query": "new-request-uri-user-part:%s",
              "analyze_wildcard": true
            }
          },
' "$number" "$number"
done < input
```